# Where Sticky Notes are saved in Windows 10 1607

Tags: windows-10

It seems like Sticky Notes are no longer saved in `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\`

I even did a search for `*.SNT` with no results.

It seems like Microsoft have changed the way Windows handles Notes. Anyone know where the notes are saved now and how to backup/restore them?

Answer (score 33):

Use this document to transfer Sticky Notes data file StickyNotes.snt to the new format

http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/recover-backup-sticky-notes-data-file-windows-10/

**Restore:**

> %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState

- Close Sticky Notes
- Create a new folder named Legacy
- Under the Legacy folder, copy your
  existing StickyNotes.snt, and rename it to ThresholdNotes.snt
- Start the Sticky Notes app. It reads the legacy .snt file and
  transfers the content to the database file automatically.

**Backup**

just backup following file.

> %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\plum.sqlite

Comment: This is a great answer, but for folks who want to actually read the contents of StickyNotes but don't have the StickyNotes program on their computer (e.g. they are not running Win 8 or 10) then you'll need to download a program that can open SQLite database, and use that program to open the plum.sqlite file. The actual note information is in the `Note` table in the first column - called `Text`.

Comment: seems it doesn't keep the table or highlighted mode?

Answer (score 26):

It appears Microsoft now stores them in a SQLite database file called plum.sqlite located here:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\plum.sqlite
```

Comment: Possible thread necromancy, but this answer worked for me. The app refused to work properly (said it wasn't available to my account, despite it being a free app that ships with Windows) and I had important things in those notes. This answer should be marked as the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on the version of Windows 10 you're using. Starting with Windows 10 Anniversary Update version 1607, Sticky Notes is storing its data in the following directory:

> %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe

If your Windows 10 has an older version, it is storing the date in the following directory:

> %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\StickyNotes\StickyNotes.snt

Comment: It is version 1607 I am talking about. If the notes are saved in the %UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe then how we can do a backup of the notes and transfer them to another computer ?

Comment: I suppose you simply backup the files that are stored in that folder and then move them back. I don't think that the naming of that folder will change, as it may be some kind of stable id.

Comment: Yep, copying the `Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe` folder worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Here what i found. C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\TempState

There is snapshot of your sticky note in .png format. Open it and create your new note.

Comment: there is no .snt file and even in tempState folder no image file is present. can anyone help me here to recover from windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 1):

Sticky notes in Windows 10 are stored here:
`C:\Users\"Username"\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes`

If you want to restore your sticky notes from earlier versions of windwos, just copy the .snt file and place it in the above location.

**N.B: Replace only if you don't have any new notes in Windows 10!**

Answer (score 1):

If at all you can't find .snt folder and above mentioned answers don't work for you. you can simply take plum.sqlite file and read it online or sqlite editor.

for online you can refer to http://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/ link and browse the url as **C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState**

and pick sql lite file and execute it. Post executing select Note and you will find all rows corresponding to each sticky notes you have lost. Select the Text column and copy content, you will find all your data there.

ENJOY !!!! [image]

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 you can recover in this way, there is no .snt file

1. Start Run
2. Go to this %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe
3. Copy this folder Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe
4. Replace it with new Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe
5. Check your sticky notes now, you will get all your data

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me when HDD with win8.1 crashed and my new HDD has win10. 
Important to know
- Create Legacy folder mentioned in this link. 
- Remember to rename the StickyNotes.snt to ThresholdNotes.snt.
- Restart the app

Find details here
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4wxfds/transfermigrate_sticky_notes_to_new_anniversary/